# Dynamically switch between field sets in html

Tags: javascript, html, fieldset

I currently have a dropdown field that `onchange` will input the value.

```
    function CurrentStatusChanged() {
       var currentS1 = document.getElementById("currentStatus1").value;
       var currentS2 = document.getElementById("currentStatus2").value;

       document.getElementById("currentStatusView1").innerHTML = "You selected: " + currentS1;
       document.getElementById("currentStatusView2").innerHTML = "You selected: " + currentS2;
    }
```

I have many fieldsets created and then correct fieldset needs to show dependent on the what selected in the dropdown box.

**My question is:**
What is the best approach? As I don't feel innerHTML then all of the code is good practise.

```
 <fieldset class="employed">
<h2>Employed</h2>
<!-- Textarea -->
<div class="form-group">
  <label class="col-md-4 control-label" for="partTime">If Part Time, please detail your contractual hours per week</label>
  <div class="col-md-4">                     
    <textarea class="form-control" id="partTime" name="partTime"></textarea>
  </div>
</div>

<!-- Text input-->
<div class="form-group">
  <label class="col-md-4 control-label" for="numberOfJobs">Number of Jobs</label>  
  <div class="col-md-4">
  <input id="numberOfJobs" name="numberOfJobs" type="text" placeholder="" class="form-control input-md" required="">

  </div>
</div>

<!-- Text input-->
<div class="form-group">
  <label class="col-md-4 control-label" for="jobDescriptionTitle">Job Description / Title</label>  
  <div class="col-md-4">
  <input id="jobDescriptionTitle" name="jobDescriptionTitle" type="text" placeholder="" class="form-control input-md" required="">

  </div>
</div>
```

I am trying to add a field set like the one above to a container, however i have at least 12 that change dependent on the drop-down. kindisch answer doesn't allow mt use the complete field set but is on the right track i believe.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use templates for that. For example:

```js
var storage = [],
    select = document.getElementById("selection"),
    container = document.getElementById("container");

select.addEventListener("change", function() {
  var _id = select.value,
      _tpl = document.getElementById(_id);

  save();
  container.innerHTML = _tpl.innerHTML;
  update();
}, false);

// Save current state
function save() {
  var _fields = container.getElementsByClassName("form-control");

  for (var i = 0; i < _fields.length; i++) {
    storage[_fields[i].name] = _fields[i].value;
  }
}

// Fill input fields of element
function update() {
  var _fields = container.getElementsByClassName("form-control");
  
  for (var i = 0; i < _fields.length; i++) {
    if (_fields[i].name in storage) {
      _fields[i].value = storage[_fields[i].name];
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<select id="selection">
  <option value="status-one">One</option>
  <option value="status-two">Two</option>
  <option value="status-three">Three</option>
</select>

<div id="container"></div>

<script type="text/html" id="status-one">
  <fieldset class="employed">
    <h2>Employed</h2>
    <!-- Textarea -->
    <div class="form-group">
      <label class="col-md-4 control-label" for="partTime">If Part Time, please detail your contractual hours per week</label>
      <div class="col-md-4">
        <textarea class="form-control" id="partTime" name="partTime"></textarea>
      </div>
    </div>

    <!-- Text input-->
    <div class="form-group">
      <label class="col-md-4 control-label" for="numberOfJobs">Number of Jobs</label>
      <div class="col-md-4">
        <input id="numberOfJobs" name="numberOfJobs" type="text" placeholder="" class="form-control input-md" required="">
      </div>
    </div>

    <!-- Text input-->
    <div class="form-group">
      <label class="col-md-4 control-label" for="jobDescriptionTitle">Job Description / Title</label>
      <div class="col-md-4">
        <input id="jobDescriptionTitle" name="jobDescriptionTitle" type="text" placeholder="" class="form-control input-md" required="">
      </div>
    </div>
</script>

<script type="text/html" id="status-two">
  <p>This is status two.</p>
</script>

<script type="text/html" id="status-three">
  <p>This is status three.</p>
</script>
```

Comment: thanks for the reply and gave it an upvote for being useful, i have updated my question, your method works but does not allow me to add a complete field set.

Comment: You want to store the values in your input fields if the select changes?  I've updated my code with your example fieldset and add the functionality of storing your input values on dropdown change.

Answer (score 0):

could you use html5 data attributes?    https://jsfiddle.net/hj6bbgbd/

```
<select id="mySelect" onchange="myFunction()">
<option value="1" data-text = "text for choice one">One</option>
<option value="2" data-text = "text for choice two">Two</option>
<option value="3" data-text = "text for choice three">Three</option>
</select>
<fieldset>


  <fieldset>
     <legend>My Legend:</legend>

     <p id="demo"> text for choice one </p>
   </fieldset>


<script>
function myFunction() {
  var sel = document.getElementById('mySelect');
    var opt = sel.options[sel.selectedIndex];
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = opt.dataset.text;
    }
</script>
```

Comment: thanks for reply, i need to put a complete fieldset that contains multiple buttons, labels and inputs into another fieldset. could i link the data-text to a complete fieldset?

Comment: well you can put as many data-whatevers as you want.  so you can have data-label1, data-label2 etc.  then just access each one with the opt.dataset.whatever.  you may however want to look into some kind of client side mvc or mvvm  I like knockoutjs myself but angular is pretty popular as well